# Monitor keeps returning to primary

Tags: monitor, external-monitor, monitor-calibration

Broken laptop, great ideia: I had torn off the internal monitor (which did not work) and plugged my laptop on the HDMI TV.

The problem is **the internal monitor keeps returning to primary** everytime the laptop turn the screen off or is reseted. I already have set monitor config and still keeps returning (and treating TV as a data show or something).

The point is as the laptop doesn't show anything on TV, I can't even be changing it (I've to guess where is the text box to put the password on login). Someone could please post a way to keep the TV as primary?

Comment: This is typically a BIOS setting and how varies depending on make and model of hardware.

Comment: Not sure ehat you mean exactly, is the issue that screen settingscarecreset on restart?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Actually is kinda strange, sometimes the screen goes off (and I quickly do something to turn on again and everything continues working) but if I left off for some time when getting laptop outta slumber it just has reseted monitor settings. And if I reset the laptop doesn't matter when the monitor settings are reset

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost have you tried setting the system up to just mirror the contents on every screen? That would make it redudant to have any primary screen in place.

However

You can try to use xrandr to set your primary screen:

to install xrandr run

```
sudo apt-get install xrandr
```

in your terminal or find it in the software center

to find your current configuration run this command in your terminal

```
xrandr --current
```

here you should see every display output named

find the one you want to use like HDMI-0 for example

set your primary output display

```
xrandr --output <output device name> --primary
```

example case would be then "xrandr --output HDMI-0 --primary"

to apply the changes you made on every relog you can add them to the .xprofile file in your home directory run this in terminal to edit it

```
gedit ~/.xprofile
```

here add the complete xrandr command you used. 
example case would be: 
"xrandr --output HDMI-0 --primary"

After you are finished with your changes to .xprofile run

```
chmod +x ~/.xprofile
```

to allow the system to run the file when the time comes and reapply the changes.

Comment: Install xrandr? What Ubuntu version are you running, it is installed by default.

Comment: @JacobVlijm he didnt specify anything and this is a complete answer. do you feel i should remove the installation of xrandr from my answer? it could also be that using apt instead of apt-get would be better. please let me know your oppinion.

Comment: Don't wanted mirror the screen as first option because it really restricts my resolution.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm running ubuntu 14.04 (pinguyOS) so I should have xrand installed and set already.

Comment: @Deltab thanks, did you notice the question below your question? (in a comment)

Comment: @WooJoo ah, sorry, totally missed your comment. I only mentioned it because on all Ubuntu versions, xrandr is installed by defailt.